# Static methods to transform DTO to Entity

Tags: methods, static, entity, instance, dto

What is a better approach for implementing converter from DTO to Entity? Using factory with static methods to convert or using instance Converter object?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I ended with instance Converter objects as they may be mocked, that is better for testing